# Simple Error handling in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need a simple error handling code for my small macro, I have search the web but have nothing simple, seems to be all very complicated.

I down load sales reports in .txt form on a weekly basis, I run separate macro to do stuff and then add to a master page. Not every week do sales reports download as there may not have been sales for that particular region.

I need a simple error handler so that if it does not find the report, it moves to the next sub.

Any help appreciated

```
Sub MXM_POS()

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\Users\903270\Documents\Excel\MXMPOS*.txt"

    ‘Run macro code

    Run ("DLK_POS")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple basic structure that you can expand on as needed:

```
Sub MXM_POS()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    ' code here

ExitSub:
    ' shutdown code here
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Dim mbr As VbMsgBoxResult
        mbr = MsgBox( _
            "Error #" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & _
            "Would you like to continue?", vbExclamation Or vbYesNo)

        If mbr = vbYes Then Resume ExitSub
        Application.Quit
    End If
End Sub
```

When I desire a stack dump I construct that within the Source property of the Err object using concatenation with a newline, and then only display the MsgBox result at the top of the calling stack, usually either the Event Handler that launched the code or the top-level macro invoked by the user.